# Angular2 / Ionic2 navigating between pages

Tags: angular, ionic2

I'm having some real issues navigating between pages with Angular2 / Ionic2

If I try and push to a new page using the following code:

```
import {Page, NavController} from 'ionic-angular';
import {HomePage} from '../home/home';

@Page({
  templateUrl: 'build/pages/login/login.html'
})

export class LoginPage {
  static get parameters() {
    return [[NavController]];
  }

  constructor(nav) {
    this.nav = nav;
  }

  goHome() {
    this.nav.push(HomePage);
  }
}
```

I receive an error stating:

> "push" is not a function

If I try a different tact and try and set homepage as the root like so:

```
import {IonicApp, Page, NavController} from 'ionic-angular';
import {HomePage} from '../home/home';

@Page({
  templateUrl: 'build/pages/login/login.html'
})
export class LoginPage {
  static get parameters() {
    return [[IonicApp], [NavController]];
  }

  constructor(app, nav) {
    this.app = app;
    this.nav = nav;
  }

  goHome() {
    let nav = this.app.getComponent('nav');
    nav.setRoot(HomePage);
  }
}
```

I receive an error stating:

> "app" is not defined

Please could somebody give me some pointers? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I think is going wrong is you aren't declaring `app` and `nav` as variables inside the class, so when you assign them in the constructor `this.app` and `this.nav` don't actually exist giving you the undefined error.

I see two options to get around this...

**Option 1**

In the constructor define the `app` and `nav` parameters as `public` or `private` and this will automatically create the variable in the class for you (this is the common option when dealing with imported classes). An example would be:

```
export class LoginPage {
  static get parameters() {
    return [[NavController]];
  }

  constructor(public nav) { }

  goHome() {
    this.nav.push(HomePage);
  }
}
```

**Option 2**

Define variables in the class before the constructor method (this is more common for your own custom variables especially using a model class). An example of this would be:

```
export class LoginPage {
  customVariable: string;

  static get parameters() {
    return [[NavController]];
  }

  constructor(public nav) {
    this.customVariable = "test string";
  }

  goHome() {
    this.nav.push(HomePage);
  }
}
```

Hope this helps and you understand the different uses.

Comment: Thanks so much Will, that's a great help and much appreciated.